# SQL Filter SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I need to filter my select statement to only grab a value is a bit value is true. For example

```
 DECLARE
 @Value AS NVARCHAR(20) = 'Some Value'
 @BIT AS BIT = 1,
 @Stuff AS NVARCHAR(20) = 'Stuff'

 SELECT 
     @Stuff,
     IF @BIT = 1 BEGIN @Value END ELSE BEGIN '' END
```

Something like this basically. I only want to select the value if its true. I have multiple checkboxes and the data should only pull that data back if the user selects one of those check boxes so I'm using bit's to track if its checked or not. Thanks in advance

Comment: The code for whatever application has those check boxes is a better place to deal with this than a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` not `IF`:

```
SELECT 
    @Stuff,
    CASE WHEN @BIT = 1 THEN @Value ELSE '' END
```

or

```
CASE @BIT WHEN 1 THEN @Value ELSE '' END
```

Comment: thanks Alex, that should work in this case. I'm using the data to build a report so by having a no name column it should just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to do, so I will give you several approaches:

If you are limiting your select statement, you can do:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE myBitField = 1
```

or, if your bit field is a variable that's being passed in, you can do:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE myBitField = @BIT
```

If you don't want to limit your select results, you can use a case statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @BIT = 1 THEN @Value ELSE '' END as BitResult
FROM ...
```